# Python big texts comparing

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not at good with math and I post my question here. Hope, will not get tons of dislikes.
I have a lot of big texts from 200.000 to 1.000.000 chars in each of them. And I need to compare texts to find duplicates. I decided to use fingerprint (md5 hashing) and then compare the fingerprint. But then I realised a new way of comparison - count chars in text.

So which one will work faster and which one will get less CPU power?

P.S. IMPORTANT: there CANNOT be 2 or more different texts with the same chars count

Comment: Are they exact duplicates or near duplicates? Second, how much is "a lot of texts"?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the length of the string will be a lot faster and use less cpu power

This is because it is only one task and is easy for python and has the benifet of being an in built function.
However to preform an md5, it will need to do calculations on each character to produce the overall hash which will take a lot longer.

Answer (score 0):

If the texts are exact duplicates you can get the hashes, or even faster, the lengths of texts and sort the lengths (coupled by id of text or by text reference itself) identifying the repetitions of lengths (or hashes).
For sorting you can use fast sorting algorithm, for example quicksort.
In fact there is even special *nix command line utility for sorting the items with support of duplicate removal, it is `sort -u`.

If the texts are near duplicates, not exact ones, the things go harder, you need to use special duplication aware  hashing algorithms and sort the resultant hashes using their similarity metrics advanced so they count near things similar if distance between two compared items is lesser then some threshold of similarly.
Then again pass by resulting sorted list and get the near duplicates.